# testing website offline with .html extension

Tags: html, web, offline

I'm working on my website and I always test it offline before I upload it to the server. If I use the .htm extension to link different pages together, everything works like it should offline but if I change it to .html then it doesn't work.

So when I'm testing my website offline and if I click on the "news" button, it takes me to the news page which is good. If I change the extension to ".html" instead of ".htm", it stops working offline. It doesn't take me to the news page after that.

```
<li id="news"> <a href="news/index.htm">News</a></li>
```

Is there a way to get around this? I'd like to be able to test my website offline and still use the correct extensions. Why does it work only with .htm and not .html?

Comment: Did you rename both the file and the link in the code? That could cause some problems.

Comment: I wrote my code in Notepad++ and then saved it with the "Hyper Text Markup Language" extension. I thought notepad++ would handle that for me.

Comment: Did it handle that for you?

Comment: Just checked the file extension and Notepad++ apparently had saved it as .xhtml. I fixed it now. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the extension is correct in the code and on the file.